# How to change color of whitespace characters?

Tags: python, pyside2, qtextedit

I'm making a text editor using Qt and Python(PySide2). Like most other text editors, I want to make visible whitespaces(space, tab, new line...) and succeed it. QTextEdit and QTextOption show whitespace characters as visible special characters. (space to dot, tab to arrow, new line to reverse-P)

But the colors of those special characters are same with other characters. I think it will be more readable if the colors are different.

How to change the color of the  special characters of whitespaces?

```
orgText = """
\t\tAll those moments
\t\twill be lost
  in time
  like tears
in rain.
       It's time to die."""
option = QtGui.QTextOption()
option.setFlags(QtGui.QTextOption.ShowTabsAndSpaces | QtGui.QTextOption.ShowLineAndParagraphSeparators)
self.teOrg.setPlainText(orgText)
self.teOrg.document().setDefaultTextOption(option)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give a special based on the text then you should use QSyntaxHighlighter. To do this you must get the start and end of the pattern and change the format using `setFormat()`.

I could only modify the format of the space (`" "`) and the tab (`"\t"`) but not the paragraph separators(`¶`):

```py
import re
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


orgText = """
\t\tAll those moments
\t\twill be lost
  in time
  like tears
in rain.
       It's time to die."""


class Highlighter(QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Highlighter, self).__init__(parent)

        space_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        space_format.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("salmon"))

        tab_format = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
        tab_format.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("lightgray"))

        self.highlightingRules = [
            (r"( )\1*", space_format),
            (r"(\t)\1*", tab_format),
        ]

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        for pattern, fmt in self.highlightingRules:
            expression = re.compile(pattern)
            m = expression.search(text)
            while m is not None:
                start, end = m.span()
                self.setFormat(start, end - start, fmt)
                m = expression.search(text, end + 1)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.teOrg = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.teOrg)

        self.teOrg.setPlainText(orgText)

        option = QtGui.QTextOption()
        option.setFlags(
            QtGui.QTextOption.ShowTabsAndSpaces
            | QtGui.QTextOption.ShowLineAndParagraphSeparators
        )
        self.teOrg.document().setDefaultTextOption(option)
        self.highlighter = Highlighter(self.teOrg.document())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(320, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for our answer! I already tried using regular expression not to change color but only make whitespaces visible. The disadvantage of this method is that it is slow. I'm find a way using Qt's built-in functionality.

Comment: @snoman This is Qt's own functionality, the weak point is the use of regex, so if you want to improve efficiency then look for a substitute to regex (I'm not an expert in regex so my expression probably is not the most optimal)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I rewrote @eyllanesc's code.

```
import sys
import typing
import re

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class SyntaxHighlighter(QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
  def __init__(self, parent:typing.Union[QtCore.QObject, QtGui.QTextDocument, None]=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.spaceFmt = QtGui.QTextCharFormat()
    self.spaceFmt.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('red'))
    self.expression = re.compile(r'\s+', re.U | re.S | re.M)


  def highlightBlock(self, text:str):
    for match in self.expression.finditer(text):
      start, end = match.span()
      self.setFormat(start, end - start, self.spaceFmt)


class TextEditWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    # Initialize ui.
    super().__init__()
    self.resize(800, 600)
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
    self.textEdit.setFontPointSize(15)

    # Make space characters visible.
    option = QtGui.QTextOption()
    option.setFlags(QtGui.QTextOption.ShowTabsAndSpaces | QtGui.QTextOption.ShowLineAndParagraphSeparators)
    self.textEdit.document().setDefaultTextOption(option)

    # Change color of space characters.
    self.highlighter = SyntaxHighlighter(self.textEdit.document())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  win = TextEditWin()
  win.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My code do not change color of the paragraph separators(¶) either. I think it is because Qt delivers the text except '\n' when highlightBlock() called.

Thanks @eyllanesc.